# What do the characters y/d/N mean?

Tags: fedora, yum, upgrade

When I am updating my system, the machine tells me the size of the packages to download and asks me:

`is this ok: [y/d/N]?`

I know the meaning of `y` (yes) and `N` (no), but don't know what `d` stands for. Can someone please explain it to me?

**Note:** In case it is needed, I am running Fedora 20.

Comment: For reference, the capitalisation of the N means that it is the default option, and will be chosen if you press enter without typing one of the letters first

Comment: My guess was that it stands for `[d]unno`.

Answer (score 61):

The `d` means "download only", which sounds like it will just fetch the packages for your update but not apply them.

It is the same as `yum --download-only` according to [this mailing list archive](http://osdir.com/ml/fedora-test-list/2013-06/msg00462.html).

Comment: Worth noting that the man page for yum says under `--downloadonly`: `Don't update, just download. This is done in the background, so the yum lock is released for other operations. This can also be chosen by typing 'd'ownloadonly at the transaction confirmation prompt.`